# Pass a record queried in one controller to another controller in Grails

Tags: grails

I have two controllers Controller A and Controller B.

In controller A I have a method show() where i am querying and instantiating a record.

```
show()
{
    def lstRecord ="Select FieldA, FieldB from TableA where Id='IdA' LIMIT 1"
    def objRecord = lstRecord[0]
 }
```

How can I access fields of objRecord such as objRecord.FieldA or objRecord.FieldB in a second controller Controller B?

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Why you won't query for it in the controller B? Storing this object in session is vulnerable, because it can be lost due to session invalidation. Try to encapsulate this query in e.g. service component and then use it in both controllers. It will be much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

put it to the session scope:

```
session.objRecord = lstRecord[0]
```

Comment: thanks! With this can I still use the instance in view as well?

show()
{
    def lstRecord ="Select FieldA, FieldB from TableA where Id='IdA' LIMIT 1"
    session.objRecord = lstRecord[0]
    [Instance: objRecord]
 }

Then use Instance in gsp but objRecord in second controller?

Comment: you can use the session var also in gsp